# Keep Disk Space Cleanup Manager from running while I'm working?

Tags: windows-8.1, process, tasks, disk-cleanup

Every day I'm at my desk working away when my CPU fan takes off like an airplane.  When I check my running processes it's almost always the Disk Space Cleanup Manager and today it was using 19% of my CPU.  It only lasts a couple minutes but I'd still rather completely disable it.

I disabled the "SilentCleanup" task in Task Scheduler, which is set to run `cleanmgr.exe /autoclean /d %systemdrive%` but that didn't seem to help.

Other ideas?

4/20/2016
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to delete the task?

Comment: Wouldn't that effectively be the same? (Except with no possibility to revert)

Comment: How much effort is it to create the task again?

Comment: Irrelevant if there's no effective difference between deleting the task and disabling it, which I believe is the case.  If you present otherwise then I'd be willing to note all the details of the task and delete it (or rename it)...

Comment: How much free disk space do you have?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gGteYxY (plenty)

Comment: When it runs again, could you check the parent process using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx)? [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) might also help identify how the process is initiated.

Comment: Definitely.  And I've used Process Explorer extensively, but first time I've seen Autoruns, thanks! <3 Sysinternals

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate You want to disable/delete the task that is set to `%windir%\system32\cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:1`. If you can't find the task, it's probably easier to do so using [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) (you'll need to run it as Administrator though).

Comment: The only reference to cleanmgr.exe in Autoruns already shows disabled (since I disabled the scheduled task as mentioned in the original question).  The scheduled task shows the last run time was 2/29, which corresponds with the OP.  I can delete it but I'm really not confident it will change the behavior...

Comment: I also don't find any reference to the parameter `/sagerun` in Autoruns or in the windows registry.  It also was not part of the action for the scheduled task mentioned above...

Comment: In registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches`, do you have a registry item named `Compress old files` ? (Although this probably only exists in older Windows versions)

Comment: Also try [sfc /scannow](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: `StateFlags001 = 0`

Comment: "Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 75% complete.

Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation."

Comment: I already knew I had a couple bad sectors on my SSD.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate Is there any other entry in scheduled tasks (or other autorun locations) that might suggest `cleanmgr.exe` is invoked by it? Maybe a maintenance batch script?

Comment: Do you know how to search tasks? There are literally dozens and dozens of folders with a few tasks each under /microsoft/windows.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate I'd use Autoruns for this.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate Another thing to consider is to enable history for all tasks in Task Scheduler. You can do this by selecting `Enable All Tasks History` in the Action menu with *Task Scheduler (local)* selected. After doing that, you should be presented with a summary of tasks that ran recently when *Task Scheduler (local)* is selected. You can also see a list of Active Tasks here.

Comment: I already tried autoruns, no more instances of cleanmgr.  I also have the task history enabled and haven't noticed anything related.  The next time it runs I will check the history immediately.

Comment: disable the idle/automatic maintenance tasks in task scheduler **\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler** and StartComponentCleanup under **\Microsoft\Windows\Servicing** see if this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disk Space Cleanup Manager has two auto-starting tasks.

1 : SilentCleanup (which you already disabled from task scheduler)

2 : StartComponentCleanup

In order to disable `StartComponentCleanup`, go to `Task Scheduler` and then navigate to `\Microsoft\Windows\Servicing`. Now you can disable for delete this task as you wish.

P.S : I would suggest you to delete these auto-starting tasks. They can be manually started when required by using the `Disk Cleanup` utility or by executing this command as administrator.

> `DISM.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup`

Comment: I checked the `StartComponentCleanup` schedule and the last run result (last night) was "The component store has been corrupted. (0x80073712)".  I have disabled it.  I'll find out at 12:06 if this fixes my issue.  But this is more evidence I need to repair or reinstall Windows.

Comment: Turns out this didn't fix the issue.  It happened again at 12:06 today.  I just finished taking ownership of and deleting 5 instances of `cleanmgr.exe` on my PC.

Comment: @Devil'sAdvocate: You have a Windows computer where sfc doesn't function **and** the component store has been corrupted, and your solution is to delete cleanmgr - a useful component of Windows? You are just extending the destruction of your Windows setup.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have "couple bad sectors on my SSD".
This is what the Crucial article
[My SSD has bad sectors](http://forum.crucial.com/t5/Crucial-SSDs/My-SSD-has-bad-sectors/ta-p/111486) has to say :

> **Question**
>
> My SSD has a lot of bad sectors. Do I need to replace it?
>
> **Answer**
>
> With a traditional hard drive, that is often the case, but with an SSD
>   things are a bit different. Due to the nature of flash technology it's
>   normal to have a small number of bad sectors on an SSD, and as long as
>   the number of bad sectors remains constant there is no reason for
>   concern.
>
> The easiest way to keep track of the number of bad sectors on an SSD
>   is to run ChkDsk.
>
> If the number of bad sectors remains the same, all is well.

I would keep an eye on this SSD, before a catastrophic error occurs,
and ensure having good backups at all times.

Since `sfc /scannow` was unable to complete, it seems that your Windows
installation has suffered some damage. I would therefore counsel :

1. In registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCac‌​hes`, see if you have an item named `StateFlags00n`.
   These flags control the execution of cleanmgr.
   If you do, export a copy of the key and delete this item(s).
   Reboot to be sure it is effective.
   If this does not help or the flag is absent, continue on in this list.
2. [Run chkdsk](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/guide-to-using-check-disk-in-windows-vista/) to flag all bad sectors
3. Do a [Repair Install](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html) of Windows.
   This in-place upgrade install will fix your currently installed Windows 8 without losing anything.
   Use a recent enough version of [Windows 8 installation media](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media).
4. If Repair Install fails, you would need to reset or refresh Windows,
   which would unfortunately mean losing data and installed applications.

Before taking the last two steps, just in case you end up by destroying your setup,
take an image backup and do not place it on the system drive.
Use for example [AOMEI Backupper](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) System Backup (and have it verify the backup).
Create first a [Windows PE & Linux Bootable Disc](http://www.backup-utility.com/help/create-bootable-disk.html). Try the boot disc/usb before starting, to verify
that it can detect both the system disk and the backup file.

Comment: 1. Did that.
2 & 3. I've known about the bad sectors for a couple months.  Everything else on my machine is running great.  So great, that I don't want to risk screwing it up by doing a repair or reinstall.  Either way, do you think the disk cleanup issue could be related somehow?

Comment: If sfc fails, then everything only seems to be running great. When there is a corruption, everything can be related. I have added above information on how to ensure that you can always fall back to your current setup.

Comment: I tried using Clonezilla when this all first started.  It failed.  I feel like I'm driving across the desert in a Lamborghini with a dead battery and no alternator.  I'm doing great but if it does stop I'm screwed.

Comment: Sell your Lamborghini and buy a thousand new disks. AOMEI is much friendlier and sure than Clonezilla and is what I use. It has saved me more than once. If you need more help, just ask.

Comment: Downloading now. I'll let you know how it goes.  Though part of me still feels like this is the nuclear option and there should be some acute way to fix this issue.

Comment: While you are studying this tool and trying it out, you can wait a few days to see if someone else comes up with a less-dangerous answer. General remark: I always image the disk before doing Windows Update, after I once couldn't reboot since it rendered my Windows unbootable.

Comment: WAIT: I haven't understood that `StateFlags001` was in answer to my comment on the post. See my new point 1 above. Even if this fixes the problem, you should still study disk image backups.